# Uniform buffer object (UBO) does not work correctly using OpenGL/GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm currently developing a small 3D engine. Until here I used to use method like glUniformXXX to send my uniform variables (one by one) to the shader program. So I was obliged to send them for each frame (it's not very optimized). So I decided to use Uniform Buffer Object to send all these uniform variables once at the initialization of the program. So, the material data will be loaded once in a buffer the same manner using VBO, IBO or PBO by state changes. Of course if I want for some reason to modify the data in cache I always could use methods like glMapBuffer and glUnmapBuffer to update the data.

For my example I loaded a simple ADS shader program (Ambient, Diffuse and Specular lighting). Now for a sake of simplicity the Shininess component (used to compute the specular light) is placed into a uniform block in the fragment shader as follow (all remaining uniform variables we need to compute ADS shading are used as simple uniform variables):

```
[...]

layout (std140) uniform MaterialBlock
{
    float Shininess;
};

[...]

vec3 Specular = LightInfos[idx].Ls * MaterialInfos.Ks * pow(max(dot(reflectDir, viewDir), 0.0f), Shininess);

[...]
```

Now I'm going to present you the client code to load our UBO:

```
void video::SpecularEffect::SetupMaterials(std::string const &name)
{
    GLuint blockIndex = 0, bindingPoint = 0, bufferIndex = 0;
    float shininess = 96.0f;
    {
        blockIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(this->m_Handle, "MaterialBlock");

        glUniformBlockBinding(this->m_Handle, blockIndex, bindingPoint);
        {
            glGenBuffers(1, &bufferIndex);
            glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bufferIndex);
            {
                glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(float), &shininess, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
            }
            glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
        }
        glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bindingPoint, bufferIndex);
  [...]
}
```

As you can see the code above describes the following schematic:

```
[*.frag]               BlockIndex     BindingPoint        *pBuffer

uniform MaterialBlock     [0] ----------> [1] <----------- [96.0f] //The shininess value = 96.0f
{
    float Shininess;
};
```

Now here's the render function:

```
void video::RenderBatch::Render(void)
{
    type::EffectPtr pShaderEffect = EffectManager::GetSingleton()
        .FindEffectByName(this->m_pMaterial->GetAssocEffectName());

    pShaderEffect->Bind();
    {
        ///VERTEX ATTRIBUTES LOCATIONS.
        {
            pShaderEffect->BindAttribLocation(scene::VERTEX_POSITION, "VertexPosition");
            pShaderEffect->BindAttribLocation(scene::VERTEX_TEXTURE, "VertexTexture");
            pShaderEffect->BindAttribLocation(scene::VERTEX_NORMAL, "VertexNormal");
        }
        //SEND MATRIX UNIFORMS.
        {
            glm::mat3 normalMatrix = glm::mat3(glm::vec3(this->m_ModelViewMatrix[0]),
                glm::vec3(this->m_ModelViewMatrix[1]), glm::vec3(this->m_ModelViewMatrix[2]));

            pShaderEffect->SetUniform("ModelViewProjMatrix", this->m_ModelViewProjMatrix);
            pShaderEffect->SetUniform("ModelViewMatrix", this->m_ModelViewMatrix);
            pShaderEffect->SetUniform("NormalMatrix", normalMatrix);
        }
        this->SendLightUniforms(pShaderEffect);

        pShaderEffect->SetupMaterials(this->m_pMaterial->GetName());
        {
            this->m_pVertexArray->Lock(); //VAO binding
            {
                this->m_pIndexBuffer->Lock(); //IBO binding
                {
                    //Draw call here
                }
                this->m_pIndexBuffer->Unlock();
            }
            this->m_pVertexArray->Unlock();
        }
    }
    pShaderEffect->Release();
}
```

As you can see I call the method 'SetupMaterials' directly in the loop. But this is not correct because I do a reallocation of the buffer each frame and moreover a UBO is useless used like this. The goal is to load the material data in cache once. However the rendering is correct (so the uniform block seems to be correctly initialized and the shader program have the access to the buffer):

[image]

But now if I just load and fill the buffer once at the initialization, so before the main loop, I have the following display:

[image]

However, I have none OpenGL error (using 'glGetError').

Plus I tried to bind the UBO using 'glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bufferIndex)' in the render method above, but I still have the same display!

So, why the display is correct if I call the loading method directly in the main loop ? And why it does not work if I call it once at the initialization ?  How could I fix my problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Launch that in gdebugger, stop on drawcall in both approaches and look for state differences.

Comment: Hello. I tried to find a link to download gdebugger for NVIDIA but I only found the following one : http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/gDEBugger/ but the download link does not work! I tried to install AMD gdebugger and use it but the software says I have no AMD GPU installed (this is normal, I have a NVDIA graphic card). So, is there a way to use the AMD gdebugger with a NVDIA card ? If it's not possible, do you know another link to download gdebugger for NVIDIA? Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: You should be able to use AMD's debugger with nvidia cards. Unfortunately the original gRemedy website is down, but you should be able to find the old installer on the internet. It doesn't cover the GL 4+ functionality, but should work in your case. Another nice debugger is NVidia NSight, which got recently updated; maybe give this one a try. You will need to apply for a NVidia developer account if you don't have one yet for that one though.